# What is the water level of an oblique bottle

Tags: volume

If a bottle, perfectly cylindrical, has a radius r cm and height h cm, the water level is l. Then if the bottle is made oblique, what would be the new water level from the point of contact with the ground?

Comment: Oblique meaning $\angle \theta?$

Comment: The angle theta is 90°

Comment: So do you mean just turning the bottle on its side?

Comment: Yes the bottle is turned on its side

Comment: Notice that the amount of "change" is related only to the angle of tilting - you need to have the information about the radius of the bottle.

Comment: Actually no need for the radius - the water level is h X Sin(Theta)

Comment: The answer depends on the pivot point, no?

Comment: Moti please explain.